# PHP: How to retrieve Stripe payment intents for a specific customer only

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve a list of payment intents from Stripe.

I found out that the below returns me all the latest payment intents which looks correct in my case.

How can I **limit this to a specific customer** only (based on the customer ID) **AND retrieve only specific items of the payment intents**, e.g. payment date, amount and ordered product or product ID (instead of dumping the whole data) ?

Can anyone here help me with this ?

**My PHP:**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('my_key');

$orders = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::all(['limit' => 10]);

print_r($orders);
```

Comment: If you are asking how to filter $orders, it would help us to see some `$orders` data, an example id, and your desired output based on the inputs... you know, like a complete support question.  Or do you mean making a filtered api call? https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto

Comment: @mickmackusa: Thanks. I will prepare an example an will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of the question (`limit this to a specific customer only`) It's very well explained in the docs :

[List of parameters for PHP PaymentIntent::all method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list)

It reads:

> customer - 
>   optional - 
>   Only return PaymentIntents for the customer specified by this customer ID.

So all you have to do is to replace

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::all(['limit' => 10]);
```

with

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::all(['limit' => 10, 'customer' => 'your customer id']);
```